# When using jquery and ajax, does the file load at every request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery:

I have a simple ajax that loads an XML file once a button is clicked.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "file.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            async:false,
            success: function(xml){

               //do something
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
            }
        });
```

My question is, does the XML load everytime the button is clicked? Or does it only load the first time? I am asking because I would rather only load it once and then use as many times as needed. I don't know if the browser caches the file the first time around and then reuses it, or if the file is loaded fresh every time the button is clicked.

What I am getting at... If it loads everytime the button is clicked, then I can load it once, add the results to a variable and just access the variable everytime I need the data. But if it's loaded once and cached, then there's no need to store the result in a variable.

In summary... I don't understand how caching works in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not JavaScript that's caching it, it's the browser - most likely yes it will be cached after the first request, depending on the expire headers and whatnot. You can alternatively add a JS-level caching layer through a number of techniques. LocalStorage, for example, or if you use AngularJS you can setup $cacheFactory.

jQuery sets `cache` to true by default for `$.ajax` which is likely what you want. You can override it if you change your mind:

**cache**

> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the
>   browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with
>   HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the
>   GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of
>   requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already
>   been requested by a GET.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for explaining how caching works with $.ajax and the browser.